# Nativescript send image post httpclient

Tags: image, file, post, httpclient, nativescript

I should send a selected image via the **nativescript-image-picker** plugin but I can not understand how to do it.
I am using HttpClient and I have inserted in the header **"Content-Type": "multipart / form-data"**.
The image is already saved on the device since I am selecting it from the gallery so I would like to avoid saving it again.
Could you explain how to do it?
I would not use the **nativescript-backgrund-http** plugin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not post it via a base64 string? its simple to do

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the backend

Comment: so the server requires a multipart upload?

Comment: yes, and I do not know how to implement this thing

Comment: yes, and I do not know how to implement this thing

Comment: Using nativescript-backgrund-http will allow you to post multipart/form-data - what are your considerations against using it? You can also try uploading using nativescript-okhttp https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-okhttp

Comment: I tried to use the nativescript-background-http plugin but not all errors are captured. For example I tried to upload a file without passing the token, the server repeats me 401 but the pulgin tells me that the call was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I solved using the nativescript-background-http plugin as others suggested.
I have not found another solution at the moment. I hope they solve this problem early on by implementing it in HttpClient.
Thank you all.